# Not getting the proper map using MKMapVIew

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I have created a mapview using **MKMapView**. Everything is working fine but there is a difference in the map which i am getting and which i was supposed to get. In my view map is coming but not properly i guess. please see the difference and let me know what is the problem .
thanks
Here's my **ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
mapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
mapView.delegate=self;
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = 12.9667;
region.center.longitude = 77.5833;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];

DisplayMap *annotation = [[DisplayMap alloc]init];
annotation.title = @" Bangalore";
annotation.subtitle = @"Silver Jublee Park";
annotation.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}


-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:

(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
   {
 MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
 if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)

 {
      static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
      pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
       if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
 }
    return pinView;
 }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end

@implementation DisplayMap
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;
-(void)dealloc{
[title release];
[subtitle release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
MKMapView *mapView;
}
@end


@class DisplayMap;
@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

I am getting the following map

[image]

I should get the following map

[image]

Comment: Do you know where the `<tab>` key on your keyboard is?

Comment: Look at the implementation of the first method in the code you posted. It's formatted in a terrible way, it's hard to read because of the complete lack of any indentation whatsoever.

Comment: i have tried to edit that. please see now and let me know if i need to change something more. Thanks for the advice. will keep this in mind while asking other questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put the coordinates you're using into Google Maps I go to the same place that you are seeing, not the place you think you "should" be getting. Have you verified the coordinates? What are the coordinates of the lace you think you should be going to?

Here's a route between the two place http://goo.gl/maps/TrM3q

According to Goolge you are expecting iOS to should a place ~2000km away from the coordiantes you are using, which ain't gonna happen.

Comment: i am not confused between the place's coordinate. i know those two are different places. can you see the difference in the way map has been shown. the map which i am getting is not like the proper google map and infact you cant see the Google logo also in my map. but when same project is running in other system its showing the proper Google map.please dont see the coordinates. my confusion is about the way map has been shown.

Comment: Then you need to explain yourself a lot more clearly in the original question. You just provided two images and said A is not like B. 
It should be common knowledge that since iOS6 Apple has been using their own maps, not Google's. What you're seeing is a consequence of that. If you ran your app on iOS5 you would see Google's maps.

If you really want a Google base map look at their API http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client, but while you're using MKMapView you'll have to take the maps that Apple gives you, or draw your own over the top.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Actually i also checked in both ios5 and ios6 and got to know that in ios5 by default it will be a google map but in ios6 its not like that. Since i was using ios6 so my map was different. Sorry for bothering you people so much.